# Java Date Exception

Tags: java

want to convert  String date into java.util.Date object getting the following exception.

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "04/18/2018 12:00 AM"

input : "04/18/2018 12:00 AM"

```
private Date convertToDate(String date) {
    try {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy,HH:mm:ss aaa");
        return formatter.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

What I want the date in this format

2018-04-09 09:22:57 AM

Comment: pattern and input don't match. You use `-`instead of `/` and `MMM`instead of `MM`

Comment: `dd-MMM-yyyy,HH:mm:ss aaa` does not at all look like `04/18/2018 12:00 AM`. You need separate `DateFormat`s for parsing and output

Comment: `MMM` part specifically :)

Comment: refer this for pattern https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @jhamon 2018-04-09 09:22:57 AM  I want this as out put

Comment: your code only parse a String to a Date. Dontt expect to get a formatted String with a method returning a Date.

Comment: Your format to parse your input should be: MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm aaa. And to format the output you need: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss aaa.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: “What I want the date in this format …” Sorry, impossible. A `Date` cannot have a format. See [All about java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/).

Answer (score 0):

For the date format that you specified `dd-MMM-yyyy,HH:mm:ss aaa`, the date string should be in the following format: `18-Apr-2018,03:22:15 AM`. You are not using the correct delimiters in your example.

Tip: [this](http://sdfonlinetester.info/) is a nice web resource to test date formats.

Answer (score 0):

That input is not correct format because you try to parse other format... Try to input your date in this way:

`18-Apr-2018,03:26:38 AM`

For the input you do, the format is: `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a` (04/18/2018 12:00 AM)